# How to implement link verification for sign up

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm looking to customize Azure AD B2C Sign Up Scenario by doing the following :

- User press on Reset Password, he put his email address
- Link is being sent to his email address
- User click on the link
- User is being redirected to change password forms
- User input password  + password again

Any documentation on how to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with custom policies.

The link could be a "magic link" as described [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/invoking-the-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-journey-with-a-jwt-e9e3ff0560a3).

You could have a new self-asserting technical profile that just asks for an email address. This would then call a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw) that generates the "magic link" and sends the email.